# How to create italic/bold fonts automatically in Apache FOP?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, apache-fop

Suppose I'm creating a PDF file using Apache FOP. All the characters in the PDF should be `Times New Roman Italic`. Since there are no such font in my system, Apache FOP will try to find the font in /data/fonts, which is set by fop.xconf.

```
<directory>/data/fonts</directory>
```

However, there's only one file in /data/fonts, which is `Times New Roman Regular.ttf`. Yes, no `Times New Roman Italic.ttf` and no `Times New Roman Bold.ttf`.

```
ls /data/fonts 
'Times New Roman Regular.ttf'
```

In this case, Apache FOP reported that it couldn't find `Times New Roman Italic` font, and it fell back to the default font, which was not `Times New Roman` and not italic either.

I can solve the problem by putting `Times New Roman Italic.ttf` in /data/fonts, but what if I don't have a specific italic/bold version of that font? AFAIK some fonts don't have specific bold/italic versions at all. Is it possible for Apache FOP to create the italic/bold style from the regular font automatically, even if the result is not as good as the specific italic/bold font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using FOP version 2.2, there is a configuration option that enables the automatic creation of *simulated* italic and bold glyphs: [**`simulate-style`**](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.2/fonts.html).

This example maps the four combinations of `style` and `weight` to the **same** TrueType font, emboldening and slanting the glyphs when needed:

```
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="Times.ttf" simulate-style="true">
  <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
  <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
  <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
</font>
```

Note that it's important to **register all the different `font-triplet` elements**; if you have only `<font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal"/>` the font substitution mechanism will *first* map bold, italic and bold-italic to the registered normal variant, and *then* FOP will simulate the styles (doing nothing).

Comment: I had to insert an extra font tag for simulating italic, otherwise the pdf  would by shown correctly , but with a warning message from acrobat reader...

Comment: @Turo That's very interesting! What did you add?

Comment: Something like `<font kerning="yes" embed-url="Times.ttf" >
  <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
</font>
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="Times.ttf" simulate-style="true">
  <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
</font>` worked fine, `<font kerning="yes" embed-url="Times.ttf" simulate-style="true">
  <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
</font>` looked the same, but with warning